# Which network interface on local host is connected to host B

Tags: c#, network-programming

Let's say my computer A is connected to multiple networks. On one of these networks is another host, B.

Is it possible, through C# from host A, to determine how host B would reach host A? The solution must handle both IPv4 and IPv6. It doesn't need to handle NAT.

One could say I want to figure out which one of host A's network interfaces is connected to host B.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is never possible to tell how another host will reach you because it is up to that host's route table.

However, usually routes are symmetric which means a remote host will reach you the same way you will reach that remote host.  You can examine the route table.  On Windows that command would be "route -n".  This is probably exposed via some API too.

If host A and B are already connected, that connection will show up in netstat.

If you control the code that has the connected socket then you just need to get the peer.  Sorry I don't have the C# code to do that.

Answer (score 1):

You might trying looking at http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.networkinformation.tcpconnectioninformation.aspx as well.

Answer (score 1):

your catch is [How to detemine which network interface (ip address) will be used to send a packet to a specific ip address?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432493/how-to-detemine-which-network-interface-ip-address-will-be-used-to-send-a-packe)

you can find pinvoke for [GetBestAddress](http://pinvoke.net/default.aspx/iphlpapi.GetBestInterface) . i am unable to find some pinvoke example for GetBestAddressEx that supports IPv6