# How to programatically determine which source IP address will be used to reach a given destination IP address

Tags: c, linux, routes, ip, solaris

I have an embedded application which will be deployed on numerous third party systems and I need it to check that a deterministic and static source IP address is used for each destination address it communicates with (I know which destination IP addresses it will talk to).

The third party must remain free to implement their IP routing how they feel fit (while complying to these constraints), I just need to check that it is deterministic and static and ideally know what it will be.

Its a C application though can run on either Solaris or Linux.

I imagine that this could require interrogation of Routing tables?

Any ideas?

Comment: Can't you just run a service at the destination IP, that echos the source IP back to it? I guess that doesn't tell you whether or not it's static, but no routing table guarantees that the IP won't be changed in future so I suppose it's a question of how stable you need the address to be.

Comment: unfortunately the destination IP addresses are not under our control so this is not an option.

Comment: Make the ip-address the app shall bind to configurable and bind to what has been configured. If this configured ip-address is not available make the app refused to do its work.

Comment: @HowardMay : You want to intercept all outgoing packets ip addresses?

Answer (score 5):

The way it works for me (both in Windows and Linux machines) is to create a socket `SOCK_DGRAM`, and call `connect()` on this socket to the desired destination address. If the call is successful, then call `getsockname()` to get which local address would be used if you sent data over this socket.

Kinda like this (based on working code, error checking removed for brevity):

```
const char * destination_address = "8.8.8.8";
sockaddr_storage Addr = { 0 };
unsigned long addr = inet_addr( destination_address );
( ( struct sockaddr_in * ) &Addr)->sin_addr.s_addr = addr;
( ( struct sockaddr_in * ) &Addr)->sin_family = AF_INET;
( ( struct sockaddr_in * ) &Addr)->sin_port = htons( 9 ); //9 is discard port

int Handle = socket( AF_INET, SOCK_DGRAM, IPPROTO_UDP );
socklen_t AddrLen = sizeof(Addr);
connect( Handle, (sockaddr*)&Addr, AddrLen);
getsockname(Handle, (sockaddr*)&Addr, &AddrLen);
char* source_address = inet_ntoa(((struct sockaddr_in *)&Addr)->sin_addr);

printf( "source address: %s\n", source_address );
```

Where `destination_address` is the address you want to reach, `source_address` should contain the address that the IP stack chose to reach it.

Answer (score 1):

I hope I got you right...

You have to convince these third party administrators to add an additional IP the ethernet port (assumed, there is just one). In your C program you can use bind() to bind your socket to this IP address.
Sent packets will have the bound IP as source address.
I use this on Linux, but Solaris should do it as well.

Answer (score 0):

I assume we are talking about outgoing connections.

The ip address the app `bind()`s to will be the source address in use. So its may fully under the application's command which ip-address is used.

Anyhow, the application may choose to not care which ip-address is used by not `bind()`ing explicitly before calling `connect()`.

---

Routing will **not** change the source ip-address.

NAT (Network Address Translation) on the other hand does change the source ip-address.