# C++ WinSock choose local interface for connection

Tags: c++, winapi, winsock2

I have a system with multiple NIC and so multiple ip addresses and I've to use an SDK whose initialization  that needs my local address and the remote address.

I want to autoselect the local endpoint. At the moment I'm enumerating all local addresses (via `GetAdaptersAddresses`) checking for the best match ( to be correct I should use the subnet mask).

But given that this  job is done by the routing table is there any Windows API that given a remote address gives me back the right local endpoint ?

Comment: Why do you need to specify a specific local address? Doesn't the SDK automatically pick an appropriate local interface when connecting to the remote address? If you have to specify an address, have you tried using the `0.0.0.0` (IPv4) or `::` (IPv6) wildcard address? That should let the OS decide the best route when the SDK tries to connect

Comment: Some protocols, like SIP or SDP, states that the local IP should be in the message body. Hence you need to know that before sending the message.

Comment: @leiflundgren related:  https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2432493/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> is there any Windows API that given a remote address gives me back the right local endpoint ?

Have a look at [`GetBestInterface()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365920.aspx) and [`GetBestInterfaceEx()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365922.aspx).

Both functions return an index to an interface. You can then retrieve the interface's IP by enumerating network interfaces with [`GetIpAddrTable()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/iphlpapi/nf-iphlpapi-getipaddrtable), or enumerating network adapters with [`GetAdaptersInfo()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365917.aspx)/[`GetAdaptersAddresses()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa365915.aspx), until you find an entry with a matching interface index.

Comment: If the interface returned has more than 1 IP, is there a way to know which?

Comment: I would imagine you would just use the interface's 1st/primary IP.